# How to get a modal form to post to MVC action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-ui-dialog

I have created a modal pop-up login using this tutorial

[Modal Form Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/progressively-enhance-a-form-link-to-modal-form/)

Now this gets me as far as the modal form popping up.  Nothing happens when I click on my submit button (the normal form works fine when not in a modal), so my question is two-fold :-

1. How do I get the submit to post to my Login action in my account controller.
2. How do I get any validation errors to show up in the modal?

This is the script that the tutorial produces :-

```
(function ($) {
var alog = window.console ? console.log : alert;

$.fn.popUpForm = function (options) {
    // REQUIRE a container
    if (!options.container) { alert('Container Option Required'); return; }

    // Give us someplace to attach forms
    $("#popUpHide").length || $('<div id="popUpHide" />').appendTo('body').css('display', 'none');

    // Defaults and options
    var defaults = {
        container: '',
        modal: true,
        resizeable: false,
        width: 440,
        title: 'Website Form',
        beforeOpen: function (container) { },
        onSuccess: function (container) { },
        onError: function (container) { }
    };
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.is('a') || $this.attr('href') == '') { return; }

        var SRC = $this.attr('href') + ' ' + opts.container;

        var formDOM = $("<div />").load(SRC, function () {
            $('#popUpHide').append(formDOM);

            $(opts.container).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: opts.width,
                modal: opts.modal,
                resizable: opts.resizeable,
                title: opts.title
            });

            $(opts.container).bind("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                ajaxSubmit($this[0]);
            });

            $this.bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                opts.beforeOpen.call($this[0], opts.container);
                $(opts.container).dialog('open');
            });
        });

    });

    function ajaxSubmit(anchorObj) {
        console.log(anchorObj);
        var form = $(opts.container);
        var method = form.attr('method') || 'GET';

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $(opts.container).dialog('close');
                opts.onSuccess.call(anchorObj, opts.container);
            },
            error: function () {
                opts.onError.call(anchorObj, opts.container);
            }
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for any ideas,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the case, but in modal form - try to stay in the same controller as the one from the hosting view. I think the MVC has problem when the view is on one controller and the modal above it uses another one.

Also Check these two articles:

[rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2009/06/rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

[graceful-modals-with-aspnet-mvc2](http://blog.dogma.co.uk/2010/01/graceful-modals-with-aspnet-mvc2-jquery.html)

Comment: Yeah the controller is the same for both.  Thanks for the links Dani, but they are outlining pretty much what I have already, that is, they get  a modal dialog to be shown.

Comment: I've noticed another issue - which I can't explain - for me all those modal examples work ONLY on the INDEX action (default) of the controller, and not on anything else. test that and see if it helps.